# How to display modal on the react google map without marker?

Tags: google-maps, react-redux

Please help me!
I am trying to display new modal when clicking on the react google map.
By the way i don't know that how to display new modal on the react google map.
I am looking forward to hearing from everyone.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

```
export class Maps extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userPosition: {lat: 40.7128, lng: -74.0059},
        defaultCenter: {
            lat: 40.7128,
            lng: -74.0059
        },
        zoom: 10,
        showModal: false,
    };
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.map = this.createMap()
  this.marker = this.createMarker()
  this.infoWindow = this.createInfoWindow()

  google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'zoom_changed', ()=> this.handleZoomChange())

  google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', ()=> this.handleMarkerClick())
}

componentDidUnMount() {
  google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'zoom_changed')
}

createMap() {
  let mapOptions = {
    zoom: this.state.zoom,
    center: this.mapCenter()
  }
  return new google.maps.Map(this.refs.mapCanvas, mapOptions)
}

mapCenter() {
  return new google.maps.LatLng(
    this.state.defaultCenter.lat,
    this.state.defaultCenter.lng
  )
}

createMarker() {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: this.mapCenter(),
    map: this.map
  })
}

createInfoWindow() {
  let contentString = "<div class='InfoWindow'>I'm a Window that contains Info Yay</div>"
  return new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: this.map,
    anchor: this.marker,
    content: contentString
  })
}

handleMarkerClick(){
    console.log("ow");
    this.setState({
      showModal: true
    });
    this.infowindow.open(map, marker);
}

handleZoomChange() {
  this.setState({
    zoom: this.map.getZoom()
  })
}

close() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

open() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  render() {

    const popover = (
      <Popover id="modal-popover" title="popover">
        very popover. such engagement
      </Popover>
    );
    const tooltip = (
      <Tooltip id="modal-tooltip">
        wow.
      </Tooltip>
    );

    return <div>
    <div className="GMap">
      <div className='UpdatedText'>
        <p>Current Zoom: { this.state.zoom }</p>
      </div>
      <div className='GMap-canvas' ref="mapCanvas">
      </div>
    </div>

      <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Sourland Mountain Preserve Climbs</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <h4>Sourland Mountain Preserve</h4>
          <p>Climbing is allowed in blank, but watch out for blank.</p>

          <h4>This is a Popover</h4>
          <p>there is a <OverlayTrigger overlay={popover}><a href="#">popover</a></OverlayTrigger> here</p>

          <h4>Tooltips in a modal</h4>
          <p>there is a <OverlayTrigger overlay={tooltip}><a href="#">tooltip</a></OverlayTrigger> here</p>

          <hr />

        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  }
```